# How can i compare all atributes of 2 collections and return the different object on Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Basically I have collections of the same model (Item).

```
$items1 = Item::select('id','produto_id','endereco_id' ... )->where(...)get()
$items2 = Item::select('id','produto_id','endereco_id' ... )->where(...)get()
```

$items1 has a value such as:

```
[
0 => [
  'id'=> 2,
  'produto_id' => 4,
  'endereco_id' => 4,
], 
1 => [
  'id'=> 3,
  'produto_id' => 4,
  'endereco_id' => 5,
  ]
];
```

and $item2 (can have N objects):

```
[
0 => [
  'id'=> 3,
  'produto_id' => 4,
  'endereco_id' => 5,
  ]
];
```

In this example, the different object between them should be returned

```
[
  0 => [
  'id'=> 2,
  'produto_id' => 4,
  'endereco_id' => 4,
  ]
];
```

Can i do this without iterate of all objects comparing one by one attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can use collection diff method ([Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-diff))

`$diff = $items1->diff($items2);`

Comment: I have tried but always return an empty array, even in the example I gave. This doesnt work for objects or i doing something wrong.

Comment: Problem can be that Laravel 5 it has different as 7. Here you can see, that in 7 it should work: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-collections#method-diff

Comment: I tested it on Laravel 5.2 and IT works for me: `$users = \App\User::whereIn('id', [1,2])->get(); $users2 = \App\User::whereIn('id', [2])->get(); dd($users->diff($users2));` Dump contains collection of user with ID 1.